# Does Laravel 7 Validation support validating the value in an Authorization header?

Tags: php, laravel, validation, frameworks, laravel-7

I would like to validate the token that comes in the Authorization Bearer HTTP request header. I know that Laravel has the Validation functionality which one can use to validate the parameters that were passed in the body portion of the request.

Does it also have a way to validate the values in certain HTTP headers or should i just use Middleware for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Laravel default `token_api` as your api guard,
just make sure your user model inherits from `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User`

read the resource code about how Laravel validate the `Bearer Token` in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/TokenGuard.php`

```php
public function getTokenForRequest()
{
    $token = $this->request->query($this->inputKey);

    if (empty($token)) {
        $token = $this->request->input($this->inputKey);
    }

    if (empty($token)) {
        $token = $this->request->bearerToken();
    }

    if (empty($token)) {
        $token = $this->request->getPassword();
    }

    return $token;
}
```

You can see, Laravel will check the `inputKey` wheather the request has `api_token` first.
So you could add a middleware for validating the authorization.
Maybe the default `auth:api` is enough for it

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function(){
   ...
});
```

But using `api_token` as your api guard is not safe for your app, maybe you should use [Sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/sanctum) instead of it.